# Pandas: How to replace values in a Data Frame using other Data Frame's columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the values in a dataframe A with "1" using another data frame as reference to map it, something like this:

Original Data Frame A:

```
Index  201901    201902    201903
a      0         0         0
b      0         0         0
c      0         0         0
d      0         0         0
```

Reference Data Frame B

```
Index  Month
a      201902
b      201901
```

The result Data Frame C

```
Index  201901    201902    201903
a      0         1         0
b      1         0         0
c      0         0         0
d      0         0         0
```

I've tried with loc but haven't found a way to make it work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy assign

```
df.values[df.index.get_indexer(dfb.index),df.columns.get_indexer(dfb.month)]=1
df
Out[1081]: 
   201901  201902  201903
a       0       1       0
b       1       0       0
c       0       0       0
d       0       0       0
```

Comment: @user3241688 yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 4):

You can use `df.iterrows()` to iterate through the rows of the second dataframe and use `df.at[]` to set the values where you need to.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]], columns=['201901', '201902', '201903'])
df.index=['a', 'b','c', 'd']
print(df)
#    201901  201902  201903
# a       0       0       0
# b       0       0       0
# c       0       0       0
# d       0       0       0

dfb = pd.DataFrame(['201902', '201901'], columns=['month'])
dfb.index = ['a', 'b']
print(dfb)
#     month
# a  201902
# b  201901

for i, row in dfb.iterrows():
    df.at[i, row] = 1

print(df)
#    201901  201902  201903
# a       0       1       0
# b       1       0       0
# c       0       0       0
# d       0       0       0
```

Comment: Also, use `at` instead of `loc`

Comment: I actually managed to do it with this solution, but I didn't like it because of the loops. I'd rather do it full pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's no need to iterate. I have a simple solution using `pd.get_dummies` and `pd.DataFrame.update`

```
dfA.update(pd.get_dummies(dfB.Month.apply(str)))
```

I used the `.apply(str)` because the content of dfB registered as an integer but the columns from A are strings, so the `update` won't work if the fields don't match

#### Output:

```
       201901  201902  201903
Index                        
a         0.0     1.0       0
b         1.0     0.0       0
c         0.0     0.0       0
d         0.0     0.0       0
```

Comment: This is the right pandas' way for this type of question

Comment: Can this be used without touching the other values in A? This solution is replacing with 0s the other values in the index,column combinations from B.

Comment: sure, just make a copy of `dfA` (`dfC = dfA.copy()`) and use solution on the copy.